VSCode's "Open folder in container" is there a Codespaces equivalent?
I have my DevContainer config in a subfolder as described here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/configure-separate-containers
And it works fine in VSCode, but I can't see a way to do that in the GitHub Codespace editor.
There is no "Open in Codespaces" button except at the root of the project and no "reopen in..." controls I could find in Codespaces.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
